# Android Firebase Distribution with applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I already
An app called com.temp.release has been distributed and used, and it was being tested internally through the Firebase Distribution function.

To use Test Server, we would like to deploy an additional app called com.temp.release.test through applicationIdSuffix, but the package is not registered in Google Play Console and cannot be deployed through Firebase Distribution.
Can I use the distribution function of the app called com.temp.release.test separately without registering the app in Google Play Console?